# ASP.NET Core : Tag helper "select" is empty

Tags: c#, html, select, asp.net-core, tag-helpers

I need to have a view with select element. I have the following VM class:

```
public class EditTicketVM
{
    public EditTicketVM()
    {
        Statuses = new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem>{
            new SelectListItem("Open", "open"),
            new SelectListItem("Pending", "pending"),
            new SelectListItem("Hold", "hold"),
            new SelectListItem("Solved", "solved"),
            new SelectListItem("Closed", "closed"),
        });

    }

    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }

    public SelectList Statuses { get; set; }
}
```

and select element on page:

```
<select asp-for="Status" class="form-control" asp-items="Model.Statuses" />
```

But on result page this element is empty:

[image]

what is incorrect in my code?

Comment: instead of ```<select asp-for="Status" class="form-control" asp-items="Model.Statuses" />```  I am not sure why but what worked for me is ```<select asp-for="Status" class="form-control" asp-items="Model.Statuses"> </select>``` . So if we close select with ```/>``` it will not work for model binding in MVC Core. When I tried by adding a complete closing tag ```</select>```, it worked. This is strange.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have tested your code on my side. Problem is in your `select` tag. You are using self closing select tag. This will not work. Write your select tag as follows:

```
<select asp-for="Status" class="form-control" asp-items="Model.Statuses">
   <option value="">Select Status</option>
</select>
```

You have also problem in your `SelectList` initialization. The way you have initialized `SelectList` would not work. Initialize your `SelectList` as follows:

```
public EditTicketVM()
{
   Statuses = new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem> {
       new SelectListItem(){Text = "Open", Value = "open"},
       new SelectListItem(){Text = "Pending", Value = "pending"},
       new SelectListItem(){Text = "Hold", Value = "hold"},
       new SelectListItem(){Text = "Solved", Value = "solved"},
       new SelectListItem(){Text = "Closed", Value = "closed"},
    },"Value","Text");
}
```